# Override the gform in taglib in grails

Tags: grails, taglib

I try to override the g:form in the taglib.Below is my code.

```
    def advancedSearchFormAttrs=["method":"post"]
    String advancedSearchForm=g.form(advancedSearchFormAttrs)
    sb<<"""<fieldset class="search-advanced collapsed"style="border: 1px solid #CCC;padding:0px 21px 0px 21px;border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;min-height:24px;">
    <legend>
        <span id="advancedsearch"> <label for="advancedsearch">Advanced Search
        </label>
        </span>
    </legend>
    ${advancedSearchForm}
    **<div id="searchcontent">
        <div class="advanced-content-search">
            <label for="Criteria Name">Criteria Name <span
                class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            ${searchSelect}
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 338px;">
            <label for="Enter Your Search Here"> Enter Your Search Here <span
                class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            ${advancedSearchTextBox}
        </div>
        ${advancedSearchActionButton}
    </div>

</fieldset>"""**.
```

Here i have override the g:form functionality.Its working fine.
The problem is the  i am not able to place the from div id="searchcontent" the end of the code(code between the that is marked in bold). within the form to get posted when the submit button is get clicked.
help me how to place the code from the div id="searchcontent" to the end within the form.

Comment: I tried and got that part right, by removing ${searchSelect},${advancedSearchTextBox}, and ${advancedSearchActionButton}, which are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

`g.form` as a closure takes 2 arguments :

- attrs : A Map with arguments
- body : Inner body of the `form` element

Here, how to use in your sample :

```
def advancedSearchFormAttrs=["method":"post"]
sb << g.form(advancedSearchFormAttrs, 
"""<fieldset class="search-advanced collapsed" style="border: 1px solid #CCC;padding:0px 21px 0px 21px;border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;min-height:24px;">
    <legend>
        <span id="advancedsearch"> <label for="advancedsearch">Advanced Search</label></span>
    </legend>
    <div id="searchcontent">
        <div class="advanced-content-search">
            <label for="Criteria Name">Criteria Name <span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
        ${searchSelect}
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 338px;">
            <label for="Enter Your Search Here"> Enter Your Search Here <span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
            ${advancedSearchTextBox}
        </div>
        ${advancedSearchActionButton}
    </div>
</fieldset>""")
```